# Sublime​Code​Intel vs All Autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimecodeintel

I couldn't figure out which one of this two popular plugins are working better in autocompleting feature in the Sublime 3 environment. What exactly are the differences?
Moreover, I am wondering whether they can work properly along each other without messing it up. Could you help me out on this?

The plugins can be found [here](https://packagecontrol.io/browse/popular).

Answer (score 5):

I imagine you've found it out by yourself in the meantime but maybe for other people wondering the same thing.

The plugins seem to work well along each other.
The differences are:

- All Autocomplete is going to autocomplete symbols you defined yourself in your code, across different documents that are open in your text editor
- SublimeCodeIntel provides autocompletion for symbols defined by the programming language you're using, by default